# React, Redux, NextJS Weird state race overrides

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-saga

I have an app with 2 reducers (city and doctor)
I use sagas.
I have a problem that with weird state overrides.

For example here is the start of fetch doctors action. As you see state was changed for doctor `isLoading: false` to `isLoading: true`
[image]

After that fetch cities action was started right before. And `isLoading` for doctors was changed back to `false`. 
[image]

On every action dispatch, another reducer state reset.

[image]
[image]

I have doubt that it's a NextJS specific problem so root store is creating couple of times and cause a race condition.

Technologies: react, redux, react-redux, next-redux-wrapper, next-redux-saga, redux-saga

app.js

```
....
export default withRedux(createStore)(withReduxSaga(MyApp))
```

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import rootSaga from './rootSaga'


const bindMiddleware = middleware => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}


function configureStore(initial={}) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initial,
    bindMiddleware([sagaMiddleware])
  )

  store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return store
}

export default configureStore
```

rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { cityReducer } from "./reducers/city"
import { doctorReducer } from "./reducers/doctor"

export default combineReducers({
  city: cityReducer,
  doctor: doctorReducer
})
```

city/reducer.js

```
import {actionTypes} from "../../actions/city"

const initialState = {
  cities: []
}

export const cityReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES:
      return initialState
    case actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        cities: action.data
      }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES_FAILURE:
      return initialState
    default:
      return initialState
  }
}
```

city/actions.js

```
export const actionTypes = {
  FETCH_CITIES: 'FETCH_CITIES',
  FETCH_CITIES_SUCCESS: 'FETCH_CITIES_SUCCESS',
  FETCH_CITIES_FAILURE: 'FETCH_CITIES_FAILURE',
}

export const fetchCities = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES
  }
}
export const fetchCitiesSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES_SUCCESS,
    data
  }
}
export const fetchCitiesFailure = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES_FAILURE
  }
}
```

city/saga.js

```
import {call, put, takeLatest} from "redux-saga/effects"
import {actionTypes, fetchCitiesFailure, fetchCitiesSuccess} from "../../actions/city"
import {getCities} from "../../api"


export function* watchFetchCitiesRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.FETCH_CITIES, workerFetchCitiesRequest)
}

function* workerFetchCitiesRequest() {
  try {
    const {data} = yield call(getCities)

    yield put(fetchCitiesSuccess(data.results))
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(fetchCitiesFailure())
  }
}
```

**(!)** For the doctors reducer/saga/actions the structure is the same except names.

Page.js is the main layout for every page. **Basically wraps every page content in `_document.js`**

```
const Page = ({dispatch}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCities())
  }, [])
} 
const mapStateToProps = ({city}) => ({cities: city.cities})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Page)
```

DoctorList.js Component that /doctor page consumes

```
import {useEffect} from "react"
import {fetchDoctors} from "../../actions/doctor"
import {getCity} from "../../utils/functions"
import {DoctorItemPreview} from "./DoctorItem"

const DoctorList = ({dispatch, isLoading, isError, response}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getCity() ? dispatch(fetchDoctors()) : null
  },[getCity()])
  return <>
    {!isLoading ? <>

    </> : <>
      {[...Array(10)].map((e, i) => <span key={i}>
        <DoctorItemPreview/>
      </span>)}
    </>}
  </>
}

const mapStateToProps = ({doctor, city}) => ({
  isLoading: doctor.isLoading,
  isError: doctor.isError,
  response: doctor.response,
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DoctorList)
```

What can be the place where the problem appears? What parts of code do you need for the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure your reducers will overwrite your current `state` when returning `initialState`. See this [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/bmealhouse/next-redux-saga/issues/62#issuecomment-585661681).

There are no known race conditions or other problems related to multiple root stores nor reducers in `next-redux-saga`.